# Make dotnetnuke-7 and dnn7 synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Tags [dotnetnuke-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-7) (113 questions) and [dnn7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dnn7) (17 questions) are the same thing with many questions using both tags.

I believe they should be synonym-ised. Also, I would suggest [dotnetnuke-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-7) is the one to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done. I also reversed the synonym [dnn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dnn) ← [dotnetnuke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke) to use the full name. I don't understand people's obsessions with using abbreviations. Just makes everything more confusing. It's not like the name is absurdly long that the abbreviation benefits anyone...

Comment: Totally agree. I'm also not keen on having the version number in the tag (there's also tags for v6), but I guess that's a separate discussion...