# Make [dotnetnuke-9] and [dnn9] synonyms?

Tags: discussion, support, synonym-request

Tags [dotnetnuke-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-9) (94 questions) and [dnn9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dnn9) (54 questions) are the same thing with many questions using both tags.

I believe they should be synonym-ised. Also, I would suggest [dotnetnuke-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-9) is the one to use.

[Similar request for different version in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271463/7920473)